# How to include all files in a given path and also all subdirectory's files for a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, directory

Im trying to make a loop which includes all files in given path and also all files in different depths of many subdirectories.Given code is just working for current directory files.It doesn't go any further

```
import os
import sys


root_dir = ('/root/Genel/File Enc./')

for root, _,files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for i in files:
        if i.endswith((".desktop",".py")):
            continue
        else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob recursively:

```
import glob 
print("\nUsing glob.iglob()") 
for filename in glob.iglob('pesktop/**/*.py', recursive = True): 
    print(filename)
```